# "It is readily seen" and its variations

Tags: expressions, traduction, anglais, mathématiques

One turn that I always wonder how to convey properly in French in a mathematical context is *it is readily seen* and its common variations *it can readily be seen* and *it may readily be seen*. For example

> It is readily seen that a complex number can be expressed in trigonometric terms.

Such turns are common in French language (of mathematics)? What are some common ways to convey these turns?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are some suggestions:

> On voit clairement que...
>
> On remarque que...
>
> On constate que...
>
> On peut facilement constater que...
>
> On observe que...

Answer (score 0):

Chez beaucoup d'auteurs d'ouvrages de mathématiques on trouve les termes suivants.

- …, c'est immédiat.
- Il est immédiat que…
- Il est trivial de…
- …, la preuve est triviale.
- Un nombre complexe peut s'exprimer en forme trigonométrique, c'est immédiat.
- La preuve qu'un nombre complexe peut s'exprimer en forme trigonométrique est immédiate.
- Il est immédiat qu'un nombre complexe peut être exprimé en forme trigonométrique.
- Il est trivial de démontrer qu'un nombre complexe peut s'exprimer en forme trigonométrique.